# UIButton TapGestureRecognizer not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The purpose of this bit of code is to animate a UIView to a certain location on the screen. Unfortunately, it simply is not registering the tap. Am I suppose to set the delegate to something in my setup? Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class NoteCardView:UIView {
internal var titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?
@IBInspectable var delegate: NoteCardViewDelegate?

public func setup(positionX:CGFloat, positionY: CGFloat, view: UIView, cardValue: Int) {
    self.titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NoteCardView.handleTitleLabelTap(_:)))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer!)
}

func handleTitleLabelTap(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.delegate?.noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(self)
}
}

public protocol NoteCardViewDelegate {
func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ view: NoteCardView!) -> Bool
}

extension MainViewController: NoteCardViewDelegate {
func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ view: NoteCardView!) -> Bool {
    let card:NoteCardView = (view)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        card.titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.titleLabel.leftAnchor, constant: (self.elementPlacement / 4) + 20)

        card.titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 100)

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

        self.elementPlacement = (self.elementPlacement + 1)
        card.titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer!.isEnabled = !(self.elementPlacement == 5)
    })
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `setup` method?

Comment: And what button are you referring to in your question? There is no button.

Comment: @rmaddy setup is called in viewDidLoad() in the View Controller. I'm also adding a Button as a subview to the NoteCardView. I'm unsure whether to create the tap gesture recognizer from the button or the Note Card View

Answer (score 1):

You should enable userInteraction in your view.

```
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Are you sure that "noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap" isn't called? It looks so weird, I mean, maybe it's called but logic inside is wrong. Try this one:



    func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ gestureRecognizer: TapGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard let gestureView = gestureRecognizer.view, 
                  let noteCardView = gestureView as? NoteCardView else { return }
        ...
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `setup` method in `viewDidAppear` in the Viewcontroller.